# useState not update the context to other components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am learning React recently. I want to use context API in my project so I make this small test to test updating the data and pass to other component but running into some problem.

I now can get the initial testItem value from About Page.

And when I clicked TEST button on Home Page, the setTestItem function would work and it would update my testItem value (next time I click button it would console.log the updated value).

But with my About Page open, I clicked TEST2 button on it, it would just console.log the initial testItem value I wrote in test-context file, not getting the latest update value I set in Home Page.

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Here are my codes:

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import TestContextProvider from "./context/test-context";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <TestContextProvider>
      <App />
    </TestContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

and my App.js (I use react-router-dom to set route.)

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Home />} path={"/"}></Route>
        <Route element={<About />} path="/about"></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my test-context.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const TestContext = React.createContext({
  testItem: 1,
  setTestItem: () => {},
});

export const TestContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [testItem, setTestItem] = useState(1);
  return (
    <TestContext.Provider
      value={{ testItem: testItem, setTestItem: setTestItem }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TestContextProvider;
```

my Home and About Page

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { TestContext } from "../context/test-context";

function Home() {
  const ctx = useContext(TestContext);
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    console.log(ctx.testItem);
    ctx.setTestItem((i) => i + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Home
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>TEST</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { TestContext } from "../context/test-context";

const About = () => {
  const ctx2 = useContext(TestContext);
  const handleOnClick2 = () => {
    console.log(ctx2.testItem);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      About
      <button onClick={handleOnClick2}>TEST2</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Thanks for anyone replying.

First I thought it would be the problem where I wrapped the Provider but I could get the initial value and I could console.log the setTestItem function.

I knew set function is asynchronous so I clicked multiple times to check if it's updated.

I now stuck not knowing why it is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you navigating to the different route/page? If you are navigating to a different route by URL, the state is going to reset since the browser considers this kind of action as a new session.

I don't see anything wrong with your code, perhaps you misunderstood the `react-router-dom` thinking manually update the URL will retain the state. In this case, you'd want to navigate to different route in order to preserve the state like so --

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // ... in render()
  <button onClick={() => navigate("/about")}>Navigate to About</button>
```

Example in CodeSandbox based on your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-estrela-r3ckn7

Click the button on the home page and see the `testItem` getting updated, then use the button to navigate to the other (About) page, and see how the state is being preserved.

Cheers

Comment: You saved my day!  This is the problem ! I misunderstood the react-router-dom concept and kept searching what went wrong in react context. It worked when using useNavigate(). Thanks, again.